# For every new row cells copy the format of previous row

Tags: vba

I have a code(button) where you can add a new row. Unfortunately the new row doesn't inherit the format(date) of previous cells. Now I need to write a code where I can paste the new row with formats of previous row.

The code should be integrated to this following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Vorschlag V+V").Unprotect Password:="verpack21"



Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

Sheets("Vorschlag V+V").Protect Password:="verpack21", AllowSorting:=True
```

Comment: From the looks of it the new row is at the very bottom of your dataset?  Surely no need to insert the row if that's the case - there's already a blank row at the bottom of the dataset.  You just need to copy the format down. (quick way is to use a table - format copies down automatically).

Comment: Hi Darren
It doesn't copy the format from previos row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vorschlag V+V")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Cells(LastRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If I run the code it just selects entire row beneath the chart.

Comment: That's the first time you've mentioned a chart.  It copies the format from the last row containing data in column C and pastes the format into the next row down.  I guess you did just say _previous cells_ which may not be the previous row... just previous to something.  You also said _can adjust the format of the new cells "G" and "M" to dates_    if the previous row had the cells formatted as dates then it's copied the format down.

Comment: Your second bit of code seems to be copying the format down from the cell above - that's the main pointer I had for what you're trying to do. Maybe if you edit your question and are a **lot more specific** about what you're trying to do then we won't have to guess at what you intend.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I'll write the question in other words.

Comment: I didn't include the code to unlock the worksheet - unprotect the sheet, or add that code and it won't give a `PasteSpecial method of Range class failed`.

Comment: 1. Your Code inserts row after the last row (last row is for Total).
It should insert a row before last row.
2. You should be able to insert rows by clicking the button. But it inserts only one row.

Comment: Your original question didn't include any of that information, so I couldn't write code that takes that into account.  I wish you luck with finding your answers.  I'd suggest having a read of [ASK].